# suggestions for optimizing my jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

Instead of writing such lines again and again, what should be the professional way & optimized way to write this same code? Please help

```
$(function(){

$('<img src="map/map_slice_1.jpg"/>').appendTo('#map_slice_1');
$('<img src="map/map_slice_2.jpg"/>').appendTo('#map_slice_2');
$('<img src="map/map_slice_3.jpg"/>').appendTo('#map_slice_3');
$('<img src="map/map_slice_4.jpg"/>').appendTo('#map_slice_4');
$('<img src="map/map_slice_5.jpg"/>').appendTo('#map_slice_5');
$('<img src="map/map_slice_6.jpg"/>').appendTo('#map_slice_6');
$('<img src="map/map_slice_7.jpg"/>').appendTo('#map_slice_7');
$('<img src="map/map_slice_8.jpg"/>').appendTo('#map_slice_8');             

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
$(function () {
    var i = 0; 
    while (i++ < 8) {
        $('#map_slice_' + i).append(
            '<img src="map/map_slice_' + i + '.jpg"/>'
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[id^="map_slice_"]').append(function() { 

  return $('<img />', {src: 'map/' + this.id + '.jpg'});

});
```

[Try Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyAR9/1/)

Comment: You don't need the map !

Comment: `$('[id^="map_slice_"]').append(function() { return $('<img />', {src: 'map/' + this.id + '.jpg'}); });`

Comment: @wared ty ^^ I find it more readable and maintainable to create a DOM element, instead of messing with string concatenation.

Comment: Well, I was precisely thinking the opposite, I find it less readable and maintainable ^^ Anyway, it doesn't matter, this is not the point which makes your answer interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(function(){
  for (var i=0; i<8; i++)
  {
     $('<img src="map/map_slice_" + i + ".jpg"/>').appendTo('#map_slice_' + i);
  }   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For optimization not sure, but for maintainability and number of lines:

```
for(var i=1; i<=8 i++) {
  $('<img src="map/map_slice_'+i+'.jpg"/>').appendTo('#map_slice_'+i);
}
```

It is possible to find better ways to achieve that. Knowing the context could help.